What is the recommended npm release management for isolated packages?
I have multiple re-useable React Native component like Snackbar, Image, Swiper and many more, I intend to make a npm package for my re-useable React Native component, so I start googling and found out monorepo (even thought I'm not familiar with it) should work for my case because I want to manage all my package into one git repository.
currently I create a project structure like this:
root
├── .yarnrc.yml
├── package.json
├── packages/
│   ├── snackbar/
│   │   ├── dist/
│   │   ├── src/
│   │   ├── tsconfig.build.json
│   │   └── package.json
│   ├── Swiper/
│   │   ├── dist/
│   │   ├── src/
│   │   ├── tsconfig.build.json
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── ... (other packages)

with this setup for .yarnrc.yml and package.json
.yarnrc.yml:
nodeLinker: node-modules
nmHoistingLimits: workspaces

plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools"
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.1.cjs

package.json:
{
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.1",
  "private": true,
  {other property like dependencies, devDependencies, scripts, etc}
}

I want to able to release each package separated or all at once , so let say I want to release Swiper only, I can use release Swiper and the tool handle the rest (bump version, add changelog, upload to npm registry, etc), as well as I use release all.
Is there any recommended npm release management tool for such a case?
I've tried release-it, but I'm not satisfying with the result (or maybe I don't really know how to use it properly).
